# Jquery pass value to radio button

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I used jquery ajax code to run search function.

here's my ajax so far :

```
$('button[type="search"]').click(function(e) {
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('fine.search') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        '_token' : '{{csrf_token() }}',
        'driver_id' : $('select[name="driver_id"]').val(),
        'fine_date' : $('input[name="fine_date"]').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        if(data.status == true) { 
        var result= $('#search-result'); 

        $.each(data.getCarbyDriver, function(i, data) {  
        PlateEle = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'rad'});
                    $("#search-result").html(data.plate_no); 
        StartEle = $('<div />').html(data.start_time); 
        EndEle = $('<div />').html(data.end_time); 
        }); 
        $('#search-result').append(PlateEle, StartEle, EndEle);  
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {

    } 
});  
});
```

and the data being returned like this on my network (inpect element)  :

```
car_id:5
driver_id:1
end_time:"2016-11-16 18:00:00"
plate_no:"DFE82846J"
start_time:"2016-11-16 08:00:00"
working_date:"2016-11-16 00:00:00"
```

here's the form blade code so far :

```
<div class="row top">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Driver Name:</label>
        {!! Form::select('driver_id', $driver, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fine Date:</label>
        {!! Form::text('fine_date', null, array('id' => 'datetimepicker', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group filter-btn">
        <button class='btn btn-info' type='search'>Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row mid ">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div id="search-result"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

the issue is I can't save. it throws error car_id' cannot be null'.

how do i pass car_id into my radio, so once i clicked on radio button it save car_id by plate_no

im using laravel 5.3

Comment: Where do u have `car_id` on your ajax call?

Comment: @SandrinaPereira thats my Q, how do pass car_id to radio ?

Comment: But where do u want to save the car_id ? On radio value? On ajax call (data) I'm not understanding your question...

Comment: post the code of the blade in order to see how are you using your radio

Comment: @SandrinaPereira sorry for my bad english , ur right on my radio value

Comment: @JoseRojas updated thread with blade code

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me where you have PlateEle, StartEle and EndEle defined. Are those global vars defined elsewhere in your javascript?

Either way, as I understand it, car_id is being returned by the ajax POST, so it's in the data var returned to your success function?

If you want to set the value in the radio element you're creating dynamically I think it would be this:

```
PlateEle = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'rad'}).val(data.car_id);
```

Here is an example I mocked up. I am creating a data object like what I believe you're saying is being returned. When I load this page I get a radio input created. Does this work for you?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var result= $('#search-result');

        //mocking up what I assume your data object looks like
        var data = {};
        data.car_id=5;
        data.driver_id=1;
        data.end_time="2016-11-16 18:00:00";
        data.plate_no="DFE82846J";
        data.start_time="2016-11-16 08:00:00";
        data.working_date="2016-11-16 00:00:00";


        PlateEle = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'rad'}).val(data.car_id);
        console.log(PlateEle);
        $("#search-result").html(data.plate_no);
        StartEle = $('<div />').html(data.start_time);
        EndEle = $('<div />').html(data.end_time);
        $('#search-result').append(PlateEle, StartEle, EndEle);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search-result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not global variable. im creating radio using jquery. i need car_id in my radio to save it. btw still not working.

Comment: If that's not working you could try and build the input this way:

Comment: $('input[type="radio"][name="rad"][value="' + data.car_id + '"]')

Comment: yep, it's created a new radio element everytime append those.

Comment: Ok. So in that case you should be able to easily migrate that example into your real code and expect it to work the same way right? Is this working for you now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128635/discussion-between-c-smith-and-andrew-vanusi).

Answer (score 0):

To save the value on your input radio this could should make the trick:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('fine.search') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        '_token' : '{{csrf_token() }}',
        'driver_id' : $('select[name="driver_id"]').val(),
        'fine_date' : $('input[name="fine_date"]').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        if(data.status == true) { 
        var result= $('#search-result'); 

        $.each(data.getCarbyDriver, function(i, data) {  
        PlateEle = $('<input type="radio" name="rad" val="'+data.car_id+'">'+data.car_id+'</input>');
                    $("#search-result").html(data.plate_no); 
        StartEle = $('<div />').html(data.start_time); 
        EndEle = $('<div />').html(data.end_time); 
        }); 
        $('#search-result').append(PlateEle, StartEle, EndEle);  
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {

    } 
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is there any error? What happens

Comment: throw this at larave log : Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'car_id' cannot be null' in

Comment: can you do console.log(data.car_id) with success before append `$('#search-result').append(PlateEle, StartEle, EndEle);`

Comment: I got the Id. I put it on the top after function(i, data) {

Comment: Sorry but i'm not understanding what is the problem with the code :/...

Comment: its okay, u help me alot. thanks.
still confused the car_id is returned, but why i can't save it.

Comment: I think you other code in conflict with the one you shown us.. If you do ` $('#search-result').html(data.car_id);` does it work?

Comment: works, but I want to show plate_no rather than car_id

Comment: try to modify the PlateEle like I did on comment that I udpdated

Answer (score 0):

Well, adding or changing value of radio buttons is simple. For your ID in database you could also use some data-* attribute on your radio button. But remember, data-* on your form elements will not be sent to the server, if the form is submitted in browser. For more details see my working code example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Radio Button</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $rdBtn = null;
        var $txtReader = null;
        var $txtRdBtnValueReader = null;
        function doReady() {
            $rdBtn = $("#myRdBtn");
            $txtReader = $("#txtDataReader");
            $txtRdBtnValueReader = $("#txtRdBtnValueReader");
            $("#btnSetValue")
                    .click(function () {
                        // note the jQuery .val("some text") issue at this point. You will need .attr("value") for setting
                        // .val() is just helpful for reading the current value!
                        $rdBtn.attr("value", "my new value");
                        $txtRdBtnValueReader.attr("value", $rdBtn.val());
                    });
            $("#btnSetDataValue")
                    .click(function () {
                        $rdBtn.data("mykey", "myval");
                        $txtReader.attr("value", $rdBtn.data("mykey"));
                    });
        }
        $(document).ready(doReady);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="btnSetValue">set Value</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnSetDataValue">set data-* value</button>
    <div id="myRadioButtonWrapper">
        <label for="myRdBtn">your value choice</label>
        <input type="radio" id="myRdBtn" name="myRdBtn" value="to be replaced" />
        <br />
        <label for="txtRdBtnValueReader">radio value</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtRdBtnValueReader" name="txtRdBtnValueReader" readonly />
        <br />
        <label for="txtDataReader">data-mykey value</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtDataReader" name="txtDataReader" readonly />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is also a common way if you need more data assigned to an input field to serialize its value as json. So, that you could have a whole object sent to the server. It's easy to parse again in PHP. Maybe this could help you, too. Good luck!